# How accurate is Grossman's description of Nazi concentration camps?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany

[Vasily Grossman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasily_Grossman) was a Russian-Jewish journalist and fiction writer. His 1959 epic-novel "Life and Fate" opens with a description of a German concentration camp. He tells of the following features, calling them "Nazi inventions":

1. Many would end up in a camp for criticising the Nazi regime in a private conversation or even for telling a political joke;
2. POWs would end up in a camp for political prisoners, including Western allies' and Soviet POWs in the same camp;
3. Workers would end up in a camp for leaving job or even for poor performance;
4. Some prisoners were German emigrants who fled Nazi Germany; "whoever left Germany became a political enemy";
5. Along with political prisoners, there were criminal convicts (e. g., professional thieves), who were privileged and used by the administration to control the political prisoners;

The novel was not published in the Soviet Union, moreover, Grossman's apartment was raided and the manuscript was confiscated by KGB (though, a copy made its way to the West), with [Mikhail Suslov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Suslov) allegedly commenting that it would not be published in the next 200 or 300 years. And indeed, the above features were in fact characteristic of GULAG, which would be recognised by many readers familiar with writings of Solzhenitsin and others. In view of this, nowadays it is hard to read this as anything but a satire of Stalin's regime.

On the other hand, Grossman was a military journalist who advanced with the Red Army and, in particular, interviewed some Treblinka survivors. He definitely knew something about Nazi camps. He seems to talk about a forced labor camp, not an extermination camp, although the camp does have gas chambers and crematoria, and some inmates are selected to be executed. He also gives some details, like colour tags, characteristic for Nazi camps and uncharacteristic for GULAG.

Question: do any of the above points accurately describe Nazi policy and what happened in Nazi concentration camps? Or, at least, were the Nazi concentration camps commonly *portrayed* that way?

Comment: I could swear we either had this question already, or a similar one about another author. Probably another author, as I don't remember the author being Russian.

Comment: I get that strange feeling of holocaust denial. I wonder why.

Comment: Exactly how are "professional theives" described. There is a Russian concept called "vory", a kind of criminal that lives by a certain criminal code. They must never assist the government in any way with the exception of matters related to child molestation and must only procure things illegally. They are not allowed to buy things at stores- they must only steal. It is an organized brotherhood with rituals etc. There might be German criminals and mafia, but they might not be as detailed as this.

Comment: @ClintEastwood, Grossman does not give a lot of details - just says 'thieves and housebreakers'. Thieves is, indeed, 'vory', but main meaning of this word in Russian is simply 'thieves', especially when it's complemented by 'and housebreakers'.

Comment: @Jos, denial by whom - me or Grossman? If you are talking about Grossman, then, indeed, he does not mention jews in these pages, but he does discuss mass killing of jews later in the book. If you are talking about me, I just wanted to know how historically accurate are some particular details in Grossman's book; holocaust denial was never intended. How should I improve the post to make that clear?

Comment: @Kostya_I Correct me, if I'm wrong, but I recall Jews mentioned several times in the book. I think, in the beginning there is description of a Jewish family before the war (members of that family eventually get into a concentration camp). There is a scene where the transportation of Jews in a cargo railway cars is described (comparison between Jews from Poland and those from Ukraine). Most importantly -- the protagonist -- a scientist, who, along with his family appears throughout the book, is a Jew. Also it's unlikely that a Jew (Grosman is a Jew) would deny Holocaust.

Comment: @Jos there is at least a scene explicitly describing the gassing of Jews by the Germans in a concentration camp (not necessarily the same where the POWs were, as the first part is a series of separated stories) and IIRC several other alluding to Jews being rounded up, etc.), so not much of a denialist book.

Comment: @SJuan76 I'd say it not only does not deny Holocaust, but shows that the Soviets were anti-Semitic as well. There is a scene where a passerby accuses the Jewish protagonist (nucular physicist) of getting a medal without being exposed to war. His friend (also a Jew) is either fired or demoted for being a Jew. My impression is that Grosman wanted to show the misery of Jews at that time. In this sense, the book is very pro-semitic (showing sympathy for Jews) and that is probably the reason it was banned in USSR (due to tensions with Israel).

Comment: Can we assume that you have at least read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_concentration_camps)?

Comment: E.g. in regard to #2: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_mistreatment_of_Soviet_prisoners_of_war): "From about 15,000 Soviet POWs who were brought to Auschwitz I for work, only 92 remained alive at the last roll call."
[This site](http://www.wollheim-memorial.de/en/britische_kriegsgefangene_in_auschwitz) tells of British POWs in a camp that was part of the Auschwitz camp complex: "The British prisoners of war (POWs) who were housed in the E715 prisoner of war camp at Auschwitz between September 1943 and January 1945 were forced to work at the I.G. Farben construction site."

Comment: E.g. #3: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aktion_Arbeitsscheu_Reich): As part of the „Arbeitsscheu Reich“ (work-shy Reich) in April and in June 1938 in two waves of arrests more than 10,000 men as so-called "black triangle anti-social elements" to concentration camps. [...] After Heinrich Himmler's plan of January 26, 1938, authorities began a "one-time, comprehensive and surprising seizure" done on the "work-shy". These were men of working age, who had twice refused a job offered to them or given up after a short time.

Comment: *characteristic of GULAG, which would be recognised by many readers familiar with writings of Solzhenitsin and others.* When the novel went out in 1959, there was not yet any writings of Solzhenitsin about Gulag for anyone to be familiar with. Between 1956 and 1961 Solzhenitsin was very reluctant to show his works even to his closest friends, and *One Day in the Life of Ivan Denisovich* was only pubished in 1962.

Comment: From the way I read the points mentioned in this post, it seems to me Grossman was criticising the Soviet GULAG system by reflecting it against the Nazi concentration camps of the 1930s and '40s. To do this he did not need to mentioned the Jews explicitly as they were not explicitly sent to the Soviet camps simply for being Jews (anti-semitism was rife in the USSR, but never openly admitted policy as it was in Nazi Germany). I think any answer should look at that link first of all. Not knowing the book I can't make a deeper analysis.

Comment: Is there a reason to doubt the narrative?

Answer (score 10):

Nazi's weren't particularly picky about who they locked up.

Before I go into more detail, I would like to make one important distinction. Nazis used both *concentration* camps and *death* camps. People died in both, but most of the deaths in the concentration camps were from disease, malnutrition, being over-worked, torture, etc... while people sent to the death camps were usually systematically murdered in gas chambers within a few days, at most.

Now, most everyone knows the Jews were sent to concentration camps, but they were far from the only group there. Political opponents (typically Communists and Socialists) were sent to concentration camps, as well as anyone Hitler deemed "undesirable." This large group consisted of anyone who did not fit into the "aryan master race" and included Homosexuals, criminals, Gypsies (Sinti and Roma peoples) and many people of Slavic descent.

Now, I haven't read Grossman's work, but I know a decent amount of history on the subject and have visited concentration camps in Germany. And even though the "concentration" camps weren't designed to kill you instantly, plenty of people died there.

In Sachsenhausen, a smaller, relatively older concentration camp north of Berlin, inmates were subjected to drug trials (mixes of nasty narcotics to see if physical abilities could be enhanced) and then had to run 40-60km in new boots and shoes (per DAY) to [test their durability for the German shoe industry](https://books.google.de/books?id=4BCXD8XRV04C&lpg=PA797&ots=nQi5tLGQ4M&dq=Schuhpr%C3%BCfstelle%20sachsenhausen&pg=PA526). Guards would force prisoners into situations where they would have to break the rules, and could basically kill anyone they wanted at will. And though *not* a death camp, Sachsenhausen did have a gas chamber and crematorium.

Moral of the story, I think it's relatively safe to believe a lot of the horror stories you hear about what went on in any concentration/death camp. It was awful, awful stuff. As with any historical source, it is important to think about the bias/perspective of the author, but in the realm of Nazi camps, I don't think even the most gruesome ones come close to giving an accurate portrayal of the unimaginable horrors of what those camps must have been like.

EDIT: because I was asked about sources, I visited Sachsenhausen literally a few days ago, and draw from the exhibitions on display, there. However, here are some sources about this concentration camp in specific.

[From the US holocaust memorial museum: general information about Sachsenhausen](https://www.ushmm.org/wlc/en/article.php?ModuleId=10005538)

[Daily conditions in Sachsenhausen](https://www.ushmm.org/wlc/en/article.php?ModuleId=10007775)

[from the holocaust research project:](http://www.holocaustresearchproject.org/othercamps/sachsenhausen.html)

It is also worth noting that Sachsenhausen was a relatively small camp. Horrors at death camps such as the infamous Auschwitz (or others) could be expected to be much worse.

Comment: My main source of info, about Sachsenhausen at least, were because I literally toured there and looked through the exhibitions put on display at the camp itself.  I will make an edit, though, if desired, to some links about the camp itself.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but to make it complete you should specifically adress the 5 claims listed in the question and provide sources whether they are correct or not. For instance, where POW interned in Sachsenhausen or not ?

Comment: You could add details of the U.S. 70th division, [a few hundred of whose personnel were sent to Buchenwald as POW's after being captured in December 1944 - for *looking* Jewish](http://www.historynet.com/world-war-ii-today-hundreds-of-american-gis-held-in-concentration-camp.htm). There were other such incidences from time to time, but this is the best known.

Comment: Nazi? Did you mean Germans?